# Is it any way to make Quick Launch behavior similar to sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

In sharepoint 2010  only those users, who has access to list, can  see the reference to the list in Quick Launch.

It seems that in In sharepoint 2013 all users  can  see the reference to the list in Quick Launch,

but not all see content of list (list items ).

Is it any way to make it's  behavior similar to sharepoint 2010 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having full R&D on this problem, I found Sharepoint 2013 quick launch behavior is similar to sharepoint 2010. Only thing I need to do is just **activate** the site collection feature called **'Limited-access user permission lockdown mode'**, which was deactivated by default in my case.

Answer (score 0):

By default, lists and libraries use security trimming in the Quick Launch to hide those links for users who do not have access to the list. Contrary to what your question states.

There are a couple of cases that might cause the list to not be security trimmed. One, could be that you are using Managed Navigation, with Managed Metadata term sets. If this is the case, managed metadata navigation can not be security trimmed (without coding through C# or JavaScript). This is probably the most important reason why organizations choose to not use Managed Navigation, despite it's overwhelming pros.

Another instance where it can be broken is by manually adding the link to your quick launch. There are four common OOTB ways to add a link to your Quick Launch:

1. You can either go into the List/Library Settings and then into the "List name, description and navigation" and mark "Yes" for "Display this document library on the Quick Launch"
2. In Site Settings go to Navigation (under Look and Feel), scroll to the bottom, and then either Add Link or Add Heading.
3. Navigating to /_layouts/15/quiklnch.aspx. (This is my preferred way)
4. Using the Edit Links button within the Quick Launch menu.

What I've found is that using 1 will always security trim your list/library. So if you are having issues, try that  first. Using 2 - 4 can cause issues if you include anything after the .aspx because SharePoint can sometimes treat it as an outside link instead of internal. So if you are including something in that to help sort/filter the list check that as well.

It may be helpful to check both the list permissions, as well as the "list name, description and navigation settings". Toggle the display this item on the quick launch and see if it removes it. If it doesnt remove it from any reference in 2-4, and then try again. SP can be wonky sometimes, or lets face it, user error when adding the list to the Quick Launch, and sometimes a refresh can help.

If all else fails, make sure you don't have a rogue permission allowing all users read access to the list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer..! The solution i found for this problem is , the site collection feature 'Limited-access user permission lockdown mode' is need to be activated... :)